# Retrieve thumbnails from a Video file periodically

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I am trying to extract Thumbnail images from a Video file, the use case is that I want a Bitmap image for every other second of the video, I tried using MediaMetadataRetriever, but the problem is it returns same frames, no matter what the time is.

This is the code which I had tried

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 
            retriever.setDataSource(PATH); 
             for(int i = 0; i< 10 ;i++) {

                Bitmap bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime(i * 1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
                imgList.add(bmp);
                System.out.println(imgList.size());

            }
```

Is there any other feasible solution to get Frames periodically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time for the MediaMetadataRetriever is specified in microseconds.

To get the frame at 2 seconds you have to call:

```
Bitmap bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime(2 * 1000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

I've found that MediaMetadataRetriever returns the same frame for a whole second regardless of this very precise timestamp, but for your requirements it should work.

Comment: All images still are the same