# retriever.getFrameAtTime is not accurate, how can i get screenshot of video?

Tags: android, frame, android-videoview, screen-capture

This is the function i am using:

```
public Bitmap getVideoFrame(String FD, long time) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(FD);
        return retriever.getFrameAtTime(time * 1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

where: FD is the path of the video
time = videoview.getCurrentPosition();

The problem is that this function does not get the exact frame i need to get. on a longer video (20 min) it will be more accurate than in a short video (10-20 seconds). Is there something i am missing, if not, what could I use instead of the retriever?

Comment: FYI: Android 6.0 Marshmallow has known bug where exact frame is not returned by the `getFrameAtTime` API - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193194

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Bitmap bm=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/videocapture.3gp",Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: The question was how to get a frame of a video at a given time, this answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, what's more absurd it's accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use without option ...

 **retriever.getFrameAtTime(time * 1000);**

I had same issue and after I made this modification it worked perfect.

Comment: This uses OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC instead of OPTION_CLOSEST which gives the closest sync frame which is not very accurate since it gets a sync frame.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in that function and it apparently won't work for small sized video's and is highly unreliable, I recently asked this question here on `SO`, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881641/retrieve-thumbnails-from-a-video-file-periodically), but got no correct answers, so I did a lot of research and used `FFMPEG` instead, using `FFMPEG` I was able to extract Video Frames accurate to milliseconds, also note that the process of extracting frames on a mobile phone is slow and for a big video i.e. above 50Mb it often took me 2 mins to extract what I wanted.

Comment: do you now any link or something, that could help me with using FFMPEG?

Comment: There are a lot of FFMPEG libaries built for FFMPeg, you should type FFMPeg for Android on google and take the library you want, I used this library from GitHub, https://github.com/uday-rayala/video-trimmer

Comment: is it free to use, does it have an Apache License or do I have to pay to use it, because I am only allowed to use free libraries. I have searched the internet for FFMPEG, but many said that this is not free to use in commercial applications

Comment: FFmpeg is free to incorporate as long as you using open video and audio formats, look at this similar question regarding the licencing for FFMpeg http://stackoverflow.com/a/9272100/892055

Answer (score 1):

```
retriever.getFrameAtTime(second* 1000*1000);
```

it need microsecond but not millisecond.

Comment: millisecond,i forget ,lol,i used to think it need millisecond. : )

Comment: Tested true. This should be the accepted answer. Actually, you can tell it from the argument name: timeUs, which means time in µs, that is, of course, microsecond.

Comment: God dammit, the whole API uses milliseconds but this method uses microseconds. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, I Agree retriever.getFrameAtTime is not accurate.**

An alternative solution to replace the `getFrameAt` method of Android `MediaMetadataRetriever`. **AV_FrameCapture** uses `MediaCodec` to decode the video frame and use `OpenGL` to convert the video frame as RGB Bitmap. As Android `MediaMetadataRetriever` does not guarantee to return a result when calling `getFrameAtTime`, this **AV_FrameCapture can be used to extract a frame of video with accuracy.**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60633395/6676310